# Post_type doesn't work for widgets?

Tags: custom-post-types, widgets, loop

I've found almost the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796165/multiple-loops-in-wordpress-second-loop-not-resetting but the answer doesn't work for me.

I have "portfolio" post type, and I'm working on widget displaying all portfolio items.

This code works perfectly on page-portfolio:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',   
        'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>         
 (...)
<?endwhile?>
```

But when I implement this in my widgets - the "post_type" field doesn't seem to work. No matter what I type as post type - it always displays POSTS instead of PORTFOLIO ITEMS. Even if the post type doesn't even exist (and as we all know it should display nothing if there's no such post type!).

I believe the problem is aside from my widget there's blog section (loop from loop.php, no code to show, because there's just only "while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();")

[edit]

I may be wrong, deleted every line of code from loop.php and my widget still shows posts.

Any ideas how to fix that?

[edit #2]

Ok, so my site looks just like every normal Wordpress blog:

```
header.php
loop.php > widget area
footer.php
```

There is almost no PHP code in header and footer (at least no loops etc.).

The loop.php is also I'd say normal:

```
 <?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?> 
    (...)
    <?php endif; ?> 

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
    (...)
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

In fact the widget is ALSO not very unique:

```
function myWidgetName_load_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'myWidgetName' );
}

class myWidgetName extends WP_Widget {

    function myWidgetName() {
(...)
}

function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $number = $instance['number'];

        echo $before_widget;
        if ( $title )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        if ( $number )
    echo "<ul>"; ?>          
        <?php 
     $loopWithSuperUniqueName = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'anything', /* and this doesn't work */   
        'posts_per_page' => 15 ) );
    ?>

     <?php while ( $loopWithSuperUniqueName->have_posts() ) : $loopWithSuperUniqueName->the_post(); ?>  
     <p><?php the_title(); ?></p> /* it always displays POSTS even if 'post_type' => 'alalaaolbadiobladaWhathever' */
     <?php endwhile; ?>  




    <?php echo "</ul>"; ?> 
        <?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }

function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
(...)
}

 function form( $instance ) {  
(...)
}

etc.
```

The widget's code is OK, because I've developed a few similar widgets and they WORK.

I'm starting to think there's something wrong with Wordpress, not my code.

Comment: @Wordpressor: Maybe there is a plugin that interferes with your query? Try disabling all plugins and report back whether that changed anything.

Comment: Might try passing in the `surpress_filters` arg to bypass any filters that are jumping onto your query.

Comment: @Jan Fabry it displays items of wrong post type even after disabling all other widgets, so that's not the point :( @t31os I'll try, but I'm not sure how to :)

Comment: @Wordpressor: After disabling all widgets or all plugins?

Comment: @Jan Fabry, right, my mistake. I've disabled all plugins this time, nothing changes.

Comment: @Wordpressor - Add it into your query args, eg. `'surpress_filters' => 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your widget references the global $loop for some reason. This could possibly be due to the internals of the Widget class or due to interference of other plugins, i guess.

As a first step, to be on the safe side, try using a different variable name. The global loop is referred to as $loop, by simply renaming yours to $myloop you can avoid any confusions between global and local.

Secondly, if the trouble persists, test your widget on a 'page' type page. Or any other 'single' page. Does it only show a single row now?

Comment: Changing loop's name was the first thing that came to my mind, but it didn't help. I've been trying even with query_posts instead of WP_Query. For page/single/anything else it shows posts. All the time. But posts_per_page work and if I type 1 there then I'm getting 1 post, 2 - 2 posts etc. Everything just seem perfectly fine. Excepting this bug with post types. The funny thing is the same loop just work amazingly well but not in widget. And the guy from the first post had the same problem, but his answer doesn't work in my case as well. Global $post also didn't change a thing.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to post the full code for at least that particular method. So you tried using get_posts()? Also, are you setting any query related or parse_query related filters or actions? Are you doing a `global $loop`, `global $wp_query`, `global $posts` or anything the likes anywhere?

Comment: I'm using the same code as above with changed variable names. I'm doing global xxx nowhere.

Comment: What's within the loop?

Comment: @wyrfel, check the first post if you still have faith

Comment: @Wordpressor: Thanks...looks all good. I've got another idea/suspicion, actually...please try replacing 'posts_per_page' with 'numberposts'.

Comment: @Wordpressor: did you try this? The reason i'm suggesting it is because i believe to have seen while skipping over the code a while ago that if you trigger pagination, which 'posts_per_page' does, WP fetches the query arguments from the URL parameters before running the query, which might cause your problems.

Comment: @wyrfel, sorry, I forgot about this question. I'm getting the same effect for 'numberposts'. I think I'm going to give up on this...

Answer (score -2):

i could solve this problem using 
wp_reset_query();

at the beginning of the widget

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you think this could work?